# Buddhist Prayer Beads, Malas

Tags: personal-practice, prayer

How are Malas used in the spiritual Buddhist practice?

Are there instructions and introductions for use?

I am equally interested in responses from the Buddhist practice of monks and lay people (less New Age theories). I am particularly interested the application of Malas uses of all Buddhist lineages in everyday life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String of beads can be used in [Anussati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anussati) meditation in sitting or when you are out of meditation to occupy the mind with wholesome thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of prayer beads have a certain number of beads that correspond to the number of chants one should undertake, usually ending in the number 8 since it is considered a good number. It is to keep your place when you chant. I have a number of them that are 108 count mala beads for the purpose of counting off chants that are 108 repetitions.